# wrap text feature in Excel changed / inconsistent behaviour

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, word-wrap

Excel's "wrap text" (german: Textumbruch) behaviour seems to have changed.

Whitespace at the end of the cell used to be cut off (not transferred to the new line) if "wrap text" is active. The old behaviour is still visible when the cell is edited.

Edit mode:

[image]

Only selected / not selected (now):

[image]

I cannot pinpoint why this behaviour has changed.
What happend? How do I revert Excel to the old behaviour?

**Update 30.11.2023 - Important and additional information on how to replicate this bug:**

When I tried to make a test file and recreate this behavior today (as I did yesterday for the screenshots) it seemed to not work, although I did the same steps.

When I tried to reopen the original file which was reported to me, the bug was still visible. It took me a while to understand that **the original "patient zero" file has to be opened first and has to remain open** in the background to cascadingly trigger the bug in other files.

I cannot share the original file, as it stores highly confidential customer data.

My best guess would be that the massive amount of formatted (e.g. different font colors in one cell) and grouped cells spread over dozens of tables and hundreds of rows cause some sort of overload on the visual formatting.

I hope this information may help already.

If I find time, I can try and recreate an XLSX file filled formatted dummy data.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score -1):

It's not the repeated spaces that make the new line start (unless they don't fit the cell width); `ctrl-enter` causes a line break.

You could check by typing something in a cell, hit `ctrl-enter` (add no spaces) and continue typing. In the end hit enter without holding shift.

If you have set the format to `Textumbruch` (wrap text) it will start a new line at the line end character we added by typing `ctrl-enter`. This character is recognized by Excel as `CHAR(10)`.

So `="text1"&CHAR(10)&"text2"` will result in two lines if Wrap Text is enabled.

You could use this to fix the wrong spaces:
`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|"),"||"," ")," |"," "))," ",CHAR(10)),"|"," ")`

It could be used on a range at once.

Or when having Office 365:
`=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"  ",,1)))`

Comment: I'm aware of that (and I already do that), but the people, who created the unmanagable amount of legacy excel files I have to use, wheren't.

Comment: So then what's the point of your question?

Comment: I want to know either (1) how to change the behaviour back, (2) a possible fix that can be applied automatically or at least (3) the reason what has changed to cause this and why it cant be reverted. Sry, but your answer is providing none of that.

Comment: Look in the bottom. Have you tried that. Nothing changed other than maybe the column width or a different font causing a different size of the text within the cell. Again, adding spaces is not the correct way to make text wrap. Use shift+enter between lines

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: "Again, adding spaces is not the correct way" And again in response: I know that. But I have to use large quantaties of legacy Exel files that were naivly used like Word files. Your question points out how to prevent this in the future, but it's not providing any applicable solution for the situation now.

Comment: It does. Have you tried the formula `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","|"),"||"," ")," |"," "))," ",CHAR(10)),"|"," ")` that was in the last part of my reply?

Also your question, initially was "I cannot pinpoint why this behaviour has changed.
What happend? How do I revert Excel to the old behaviour?" I explained this and got: "I know, I want something else.." + a down vote.